# How to compare current time with time mentioned in the table in PHP, to determine active/expired/upcoming?

Tags: php, database, date

```
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkPTT.png][1]        
<?php
    $email=$_SESSION['user'];
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'sconnect');
    $data="SELECT * FROM events WHERE email='$email';";
    $resmy=mysqli_query($con,$data);
    if ($data) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resmy)) { 
            $gid = $row['event_id'];
            $gquery ="select * from events where event_id='$gid';";
            $myresq = mysqli_query($con,$gquery);
            $grow = mysqli_fetch_array($myresq);
            echo "<tr><td>".$row['event_id']."</td><td>".$grow['gname']."</td> 
            <td>".$grow['location']."</td><td>".$grow['date']."</td> 
            <td>".$grow['timing_from']."</td><td>".$grow['timing_to']."</td> 
            <td>".$grow['venue_details']."</td><td>".$grow['participants']."</td>
            </tr>";
       }
    } else {
       echo"<tr><td>You have not created any events yet</td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

In this code I wish to add a column to display an event is active/expired/upcoming. In the above table date, event start time and event end time is available.

Comment: Can you post the table structure?

Comment: @Vidal I hope you can find link at top of the code, which displays table.

Comment: Check out my answer, and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable inside your PHP code to get status based on your table date field. Check below code:

```
<?php
    $email=$_SESSION['user'];
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'sconnect');
    $data="SELECT * FROM events WHERE email='$email';";
    $resmy=mysqli_query($con,$data);
    if ($data) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resmy)) { 
            $gid = $row['event_id'];
            $gquery ="select * from events where event_id='$gid';";
            $myresq = mysqli_query($con,$gquery);
            $grow = mysqli_fetch_array($myresq);
            if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime($grow['date_to'])) { // means current time is greater than event to time which makes it expired.
                $eventStatus = 'Expired';
            } else if (strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-24 hours'))) > strtotime($grow['date_from'])) { //means event will start with in next 24 hours.
                $eventStatus = 'Upcoming';
            } else if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime($grow['date_from']) && strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) < strtotime($grow['date_to']) ) { //means current time is in between of date_from and date_to.
                $eventStatus = 'Ongoing';
            } else {
                $eventStatus = 'Active';
            }

            echo "<tr><td>".$row['event_id']."</td><td>".$grow['gname']."</td> 
            <td>".$grow['location']."</td><td>".$grow['date']."</td> 
            <td>".$grow['timing_from']."</td><td>".$grow['timing_to']."</td> 
            <td>".$grow['venue_details']."</td><td>".$grow['participants']."</td>
            <td>".$eventStatus."</td></tr>";
       }
    } else {
       echo"<tr><td>You have not created any events yet</td></tr>";
    }
?>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Now, I have two separate fields as starting time and ending time of an event in the table. Now, along with the date, I have to compare timings also to determine the status of an event. Once go through it, if you have any suggestion to alter the table also please mention. Thank you !!

Comment: I will suggest you to alter your table and make 2 fields instead of 3. Create date_from and date_to (remove date, timing_from and timing_to) as it will be easy to compare and also it will be manageable if any event's duration being for more than 24 hours. Then you can save time like: 2019-02-04 18:00:00 values in db which will be easy to do further comparison.

Comment: And also mention that when event will got expired/upcoming and active according to your requirement.

Comment: I have two doubts. 1. How to give input to the date_from/date_to column through HTML input field. 2. What data type is used to those columns in the database.

Comment: please update the above code assuming that I have included the date_from and date_to columns in the events table.

Comment: You can choose datetime field for date_from and date_to in your database.

Comment: I am able to take input only in AM/PM format through the HTML input element. Is their any solution to the problem from PHP side or from HTML.Please help with this.